How to prove $\forall a \gt 0, \exists N\in \Bbb Z^+, \forall n \gt N, a^n \lt n!$
I know that for a specific $a$, inequations like $2^n<n!$ can be easily proved by induction. But when it comes to a common $a$, Idk how to derive from it especially about finding the first element n satisfying $a^n < n!$.
Instinctively I believe n! increases faster than $a^n$ after $n > a$.

Welcome to MSE. Could you include in your post your proof for $(2^n<n!)$. I am wondering if it can be extended to any one of the other $a$.

Let $M>a^2.$ Then $(M+k)!>a^{2k}.$ So for $n>2M,$ $$n!>a^{2(n-M)}=a^{n+(n-2M)}>a^n.$$
Basically, if $f(n)=n!$ and $g(n)=a^n,$ we have $f(n+1)/f(n)=n+1$ and $g(n+1)/g(n)=a,$ so we start growing faster when $n>a.$ I've just picked an $N=2M$ where it has been growing much faster for a while.
You can find much smaller $N$ with a more refined argument.

Stirling's approximation says the $N=ae$ is usually enough.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation?wprov=sfti1#

A complicated way: if you know about the convergence of series, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}$ converges to $e^a$. Since the series converges, the $n^{th}$ term must go to zero. Hence after certain stage
$$\frac{a^n}{n!} < 1.$$

Let $$u_n:=\frac{a^n}{n!}$$
$\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}=\frac{\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{a^n}{n!}}=\frac{a^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\times\frac{n!}{a^n}=\frac{a}{n+1}\to0$, when $n\to \infty$
So, $\exists 0<k<1,\exists N, \forall p\geq 0 ,\frac{u_{N+p+1}}{u_{N+p}}\le k$
Then $u_{N+n+1}=\frac{u_{N+n+1}}{u_{N+n}}\times u_{N+n}=\frac{u_{N+n+1}}{u_{N+n}}\times\frac{u_{N+n}}{u_{N+n-1}}\times u_{N+n-1}=\frac{u_{N+n+1}}{u_{N+n}}\times\frac{u_{N+n}}{u_{N+n-1}}\times...\times \frac{u_{N+1}}{u_{N}} \times \color{red}{\frac{u_{N}}{u_{N-1}}\times...\times\frac{u_1}{u_0}u_0}$
Let $C:=\color{red}{\frac{u_{N}}{u_{N-1}}\times...\times\frac{u_1}{u_0}u_0}$
We then have $u_{N+n+1}\leq C.k^n$
Then $\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n =0}.\square$

The intuition is if $a > 1$ (if $a \le 1$ the result is immediate [if $a\le 1$ then $a^n \le 1 < 2!$ so $N = 2$]) each time you go from $a^k\to a^{k+1}$ you increase by a factor of $a$ which is constant and fixed, whereas when you go from $k!\to (k+1)!$ you increase by a factor of $k+1$ which is constantly growing.  So once we find a $N$ where $N\ge a$ and $a^N \le N!$ we know by induction we are done. (If $k\ge M$ and $a^k< k!$ then $a^{k+1}=a^k\cdot a < k! \cdot (k+1)=(k+1)!$.)
So must an $N$ where $a^N \le N!$ and $N\ge a$ exist?
Consider $a^k \le k!$ and $a> 1$. Then
$k \le \log_a k! = \sum_{m=1}^k \log_a m=\sum_{m=1}^k \ln a\ln m=\ln a \sum_{m=1}^k \ln m< \ln a  \int_1^k \ln x dx = \ln a (k \ln k -k)$
So we want $\frac 1{\ln a} < \ln k -1$.  As $\ln k$ is increasing such will always exist.
$k > e^{\frac 1{\ln a} +1}$
....
I dunno.  I'm sure the must be an easier way to do it but... I think that successfully whacks it with a paddle.
